# How to print this series?(1 \n 2 3 \n 4 5 6 \n 7 8 9 10... ... ...)

Tags: c, loops, series

I am trying to print the following series:
 1
 2 3
 4 5 6 
 7 8 9 10 
... ... ...
The input of my program contains a single integer **n**, which determines the number of lines to print.

I've tried to code it but got the following output:
1
2 3
3 4 5
4 5 6 7
... ... ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,t,m;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i,t=1;t<=i;j++,t++)
        {
            printf("%d ",j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: So.. obviously the output is indicating that you are not initializing `j` to the correct value in your nested loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print those numbers, you'll want a counter that starts at `1`, increases by `1` every print and is never reset by anything. Adjust your loop like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, t = 1;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++, t++)
        {
            printf("%d ", t);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note how `t` is set to `1`, and just gets increased by `t++` without resetting like you previously did. Also, you should be printing `t`, not `j`.

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain separate counters for the numbers and the number of numbers per line.

```
int nr = 1, target;
int nrsperline = 1, i;

scanf("%d", &target);
while (nr <= target) {
    for (i = 0; i < nrsperline; i++) {
         printf("%d ", nr++);
    }
    printf("\n");
    nrsperline++;
}
```